# c# Intellisense VS2013 tooltip doesn't show XML comments (i try all)

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, xml-comments

I read all questions about intellisense problems but my intellisense doesn't work.

- Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
- I don't use any extension like Resharper, ghostdoc and so on

**All XML documentation files** about custom and not custom classes are inside starter project's /bin folder . (**Build** -> **generate XML** doc is *ON*)
[image: bin xml files]

- I have **all documentations** browsable via Object Browsers
- **Intellisense** doesn't show tooltip information about .**NET classes**/EF/Identity too
  [image]
- **Intellisense** *shows* tooltip information only about **summary**
  custom classes but *doesn't show* parameters / returns etc..
  [image]
  **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Text Editor** -> **C#** -> *Params info* and *Auto List Members* are checked

So, i don't know where is the mistake :/
If someone know i appreciate very much.
Thanks for your time

Comment: Have you tried deleting (or renaming) the solution user options file, e.g. "{your-solution}.suo"?

Comment: Yes, it dosn't work (i delete and vs creates new one) . All projects, same problem (not only current project). I don't know if i need a new installation or it's a custom IDE setting (some checking or something else...)

Comment: @enrico-tirotta did you find solution for your problem, if yes then please share it with us.

Comment: @torpederos No, sorry. :/ Now i use Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and all work fine

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same today, but I believe that the parameters description should apear when you start typing the parameters (when you open the first bracket, not when you start typing the method name). 
For example: type "checkTipologia(" - now the parameter should be visible in intellisense.
Btw: it is a good practice to name methods with PascalCase. CheckTipologia instead of checkTipologia.