# Generating XML file for C# Intellisense, broken for sub-folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Using the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816980/c-sharp-intellisense-vs2013-tooltip-doesnt-show-xml-comments-i-try-all), the XML file gets generated and the intellisense tooltips work.

However, the XML file only contains the comments in the root file (SomeClass.cs in the example below).

- root folder

  - SomeClass.cs
  - inner folder

    - SomeInnerClass.cs

      - inner folder

        - SomeInnerClass.cs

How can I generate the XML files for the classes in sub-folders (SomeInnerClass1.cs & SomeInnerClass2.cs)?

Comment: What's the C# project template? I have checked the shared link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816980/c-sharp-intellisense-vs2013-tooltip-doesnt-show-xml-comments-i-try-all and it looks like there is no detail steps to generated the XML file.

Comment: Class Library (.NET Core)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to build or rebuild the project after you added the sub folders and class, and the result is successful like ‘1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped’? I tried to create your class structure as below steps and the XML file auto generate the corresponding comments in all class file and the intellisense and tooltip also works fine.

1. Create a new .NET Core Class Library project and add root class, subfolder and sub class like yours
2. Right click the project name and Properties-Build and check the option ‘XML document file’ and save
3. Add a method into each class file and add the comment above those methods and save
4. Build or rebuild the project and click ‘Show All Files’ icon under Solution Explorer and go to bin-debug-netstandard1.6 folder to open the *xml file, then you will find the comments for those methods like the following screenshot:
   [image]
5. Add another project under the same solution and add reference with the above .NET Core Class Library project
6. Go to Startup.cs file and you will find the intellisense works fine for each class no matter it is under root folder or sub folder as below:

[image]